# the server responded with a status of 500 trying to use external font in email service

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I want to inject my HTML email template to email using node:

at my HTML code I import font like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
      
      @import url('${fontFolder}/IRANSansWeb_Light.woff');
      
      @font-face {
        font-family: "IRANSansWeb_Light";
        src: url(IRANSansWeb_Light.woff) format("truetype");
      }

...
```

I can download the font via the url (`${fontFolder}/IRANSansWeb_Light.woff`) in ethereal email which is a service for testing email but I get this error and unable to load the email:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
```

Comment: If you are getting a 5xx error, it means you've broken their website

Comment: or said another way, code that runs the website has fatally failed, as a fault of the programmers